# Query to pull all the table names and column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query (ORACLE) to pull all the table names and column names in a database for a given value?

Example: If I give a value as "TEST", I need a query which pulls all the TABLE_NAMES and COLUMN_NAMES which has the value "TEST".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search All Fields In All Tables For A Specific Value (Oracle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208493/search-all-fields-in-all-tables-for-a-specific-value-oracle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Search a list of columns with a given value (within a row)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140377/sql-search-a-list-of-columns-with-a-given-value-within-a-row)

Answer (score 1):

```
select table_name, null column_name from all_tables where table_name like '%TEST%'
union all
select null, column_name from all_tab_columns where column_name like '%TEST%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using bind variables within a procedure such

DEFINE vSearch = '%TEST%'

ACCEPT vSearch char PROMPT 'Enter a search value: '

SELECT * 
FROM USER_TAB_COLS 
WHERE column_name LIKE '&&vSearch'
OR table_name LIKE '&&vSearch';

Answer (score 1):

View All columns of a particular table user use **"ALL_TAB_COLUMNS"**

If you wants to describe a particular table user use **"DESC Table_name;"**

Kindly Try this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the USER_TAB_COLUMNS tables

Answer (score 0):

This should get you columns and tables and views:

```
SELECT 'Column: '||owner||'.'||table_name||'.'||column_name 
  FROM dba_tab_columns 
 WHERE column_name = 'TEST'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Table: '||owner||'.'||table_name 
  FROM dba_tables 
 WHERE table_name = 'TEST'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'View: '||owner||'.'||view_name
  FROM dba_views
 WHERE view_name = 'TEST';
```

Note you can also use the ALL_* dictionary views if you don't have access to the DBA_ views, but you'll only see objects you have access to.